# Product images not getting uploaded

Tags: magento2, product-images, upload

I'm unable to upload product images on upload if I inspect developer tool I get 404 on `/media/catalog/product/b/s/website_draft_160204-2_11.jpg Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: Check permission of media folder and image file

Comment: check file exits or not. if exits then make sure that it have read permission for world

Comment: I've done `chmod -R 777 pub`